# Is there a javascript function that returns the date that a specified file was last modified?

Tags: javascript, last-modified

Is there a javascript function that returns the date that a specified file was last modified? NO IFRAME! It can't have anything involved with php. Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think javascript has access to any filesystem on your client / server, so I reckon it's probably impossible. CMIIW

Answer (score 0):

document.lastModified Works for me on my Apache server

Comment: No, I want it to be for a specified file like:

Comment: Well then you can prob have it load the page in an invisible iframe then call then function within the scope of the iframe